# Displaying remaining months of the year plus all months of following 2 years

Tags: php, date

I want to display all remaining months of current year followed by all months of following 2 years. Using the following code I can display next x months, but not sure how to display remaining months of current year regardless of what's the current month is, nor all months of following years.

```
$month = date('n'); 
for ($x = 0; $x < 24; $x++) {
    echo date('F Y', mktime(0,0,0,$month + $x,1)) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: @kingkero That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic arithmetic: *12 - current month* gives you the remaining x months of this year. Then add 24 for two following years.

```
$month = date('n');
$max = (12-$month) + 24; 
for ($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++) {
    echo date('F Y', mktime(0,0,0,$month + $x,1)) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just one thing though, the last month is november 2017 instead of december 2017. Shall I just replace 24 with 25?

Answer (score -1):

```
<select  name="curren" >
    <?php 
        $mnth=date('n');
        $max=13-$mnth;                                 
    ?>

    <?php 
    for($x = 0; $x < $max; $x++)
    {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo date("F", strtotime("+$x month"));?>"><?php echo date("F", strtotime("+$x month"));?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Comment: In addition, please take the time to [format your code properly](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).